# Flutter - How to create custom tabs in the tab bar view?

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs

I want tabs with a specific background color. When I click on the tab, the background color of the current tab should be changed. I have tried many methods. I didn't get what I wanted.

I want the tab color to be gray and the selected color to be blue.
Can anyone help to resolve this?

Here's what I want:

[image]

What I get:

[image]

Here's a code for a single tab:

```
DefaultTabController(
            length: 4, // length of tabs
            initialIndex: 0,
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                   TabBar(
                            isScrollable: true,
                            labelColor: const Color(0xff000000),
                            labelPadding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 5),
                            indicator: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.circular(10), // Creates border
                                color: const Color(0xff77e8d9)),
                            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                            tabs: [

                              Tab(
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                          10), // Creates border
                                      color: const Color(0xfff4f4f4)),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    height: 40,
                                    width: 110,
                                    child: Row(children: [
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                                        child: Text('Featured',
                                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              letterSpacing: 0.3,
                                            )),
                                      ),
                                      const Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1),
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.favorite,
                                          color: Color(0xffef5145),
                                          size: 21,
                                        ),
                                      ),
    
                              ]),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
Container(
                    height: 1250,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
                    child: TabBarView(children: [

                      Container(),
                    ]),
                  ),
```

Comment: Can you share full code

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the Container has its own color, but you want to give it a new color with the TabBar indicator, which is not possible. To solve this problem, you can set the Container's color

```
Color(0xfff4f4f4)
```

to

```
Colors.transparent
```

This will make it look like this:
[Transparent color Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOQYq.png)

However, what you seem to want is to make the selected Tab's color 'blue' and the unselected Tab's color 'white'. To do this, you can set the Container's color based on the index value of the selected Tab using TabController. I might have explained this a bit confusingly, but if you look at the example, you will understand what I mean. This will make it look like this:
[Changing the color of the Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pvuj.png)

Important things in this example:

- You should use the 'with TickerProviderStateMixin' expression for the TabController parameter.
- You should define an integer variable to get the index of the TabBar. The value of this variable will be changed using the addListener method of the TabController.
- You don't need an indicator in the TabBar for what you want, so you should use an empty indicator.
- You should set the color of the Containers in the Tabs to blue if that tab is selected, and white otherwise.

Full code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;
  int tabIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
    tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        tabIndex = tabController.index;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Colors.purple,
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          initialIndex: 0,
          child: TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            isScrollable: false,
            automaticIndicatorColorAdjustment: true,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            indicator: const BoxDecoration(),
            tabs: [
              getTab("featured", Icons.favorite, tabIndex == 0),
              getTab("boys", Icons.male, tabIndex == 1),
              getTab("girls", Icons.female, tabIndex == 2),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: tabController,
        children: const [
          Center(
            child: Text("tabbar 1"),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text("tabbar 2"),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text("tabbar 3"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getTab(String text, IconData icon, bool isSelected) {
    return Tab(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
        ),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 40,
          width: 110,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                child: Text(
                  text,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 1),
                child: Icon(
                  icon,
                  color: const Color(0xffef5145),
                  size: 21,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I hope this answer is helpful for you